# How is the $E(|xy|)$ operator "isomorphic" with the dot product on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: probability-theory, vector-spaces, expectation, inner-products

I am studying the cauchy schwartz inequality. I understand why it works for standard vector spaces on $\mathbb R^n$.

However I find it hard to intuitively grasp why it works for the expectation operator on a product of random variables. I understand why this is just another example of an inner product, but I don't intuitively understand why its similar to the dot product.

Specifically whats confusing me is the fact that we're not summing two columns of real nimbers as we do with the dot product, not even in the discrete and finite random variable case.

The reason for this is that the posible values of the random variables are first multiplied by their probabilities. But these probabilities are different when we take $E(xx)$ (sum of $x_i^2p_i$ than when we take $E(xy)$ (sum of $x_ip_i*y_jp_j$).

So I'm wondering if there is a way to show the connection between the expectation operator and the dot product operator that makes intuitively clear why the cauchy inequality holds for both of them:

$$E(|xy|)^2\leq E(xx)E(xx)$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the integral inner products that one can construct for real-valued functions? The isomorphism is quite clear there when we talk about expectation as an integral operator.

Comment: @Kajelad, yes if I'm not mistaken, you're referring to $[f,g]=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx$. The analogy between this and the dot product is clear to me. For example, if we take $[f,f]$ this is simply $\int(_a^b f(x)^2dx$. We are in effect taking the dot product of a vector with "continuous elements" rather than finite elements. However, when it comes to the inner product for random variables $[x,y]=E|xy|=\int\int_{-\infty}^\infty xyf(x,y)dxdy$, this is very different from $[x,x]=E|xy|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)dx$ The reason they are different is that $x$ is perfectly correlated with $x$.

Comment: So that in the second case, the double integral collapses into a  single integral. This means that because of possible non-independence, we cannot see the operator $E(|xy|)$ as a kind of dot product of a vector with continuous elements like we can with the integral inner product. We for example cannot think of it as the dot product between the vectors where each element of $x$ is equal to $x\cdot f(x)$. This interpretation would only work if the two random variables are completely independent, which is most of the time not the case. For this reason, the connection with dot product confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain intuition, you can consider the case in which $X$ and $Y$ assume a finite number of values. In this case, there exists a finite sample space $\Omega$ and a probability measure over $\Omega$, $\mathbb{P}$, such that $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Note that, since $\Omega$ is finite, a random variable $Z: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to a finite-dimensional real valued vector. Let $<Z_1,Z_2>$ denote the usual dot product. We can obtain
\begin{align*}
 E[|XY|]^2
 &= \left(\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}
 {|X(\omega)Y(\omega)|\mathbb{P}(\omega)}\right)^2 \\
 &= \left(\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}
 {\bigg|\left(X(\omega)\sqrt{\mathbb{P}(\omega)}\right)
 \left(Y(\omega)\sqrt{\mathbb{P}(\omega)}\right)\bigg|}\right)^2 \\
 &= \langle|X\sqrt{\mathbb{P}}|,|Y\sqrt{\mathbb{P}}|\rangle^2 \\
 &\leq \langle X\sqrt{\mathbb{P}},X\sqrt{\mathbb{P}}\rangle
 \langle Y\sqrt{\mathbb{P}},Y\sqrt{\mathbb{P}}\rangle \\
 &= E[|X^2|]E[|Y^2|]
\end{align*}
Note that you were having trouble because you used the law of the unconscious statistician to compute the expectations using the probability mass functions of $X$ and $Y$. This problem is avoided by computing the expectation directly over $\mathbb{P}$.

For continuous random variables, you can use the same idea, that is,
\begin{align*}
 E[|XY|]^2 
 &= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{|xy|f(x,y)d(x \times y)}\right)^2 \\
 &= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{\bigg|(x\sqrt{f(x,y)})\bigg| 
 \bigg|y\sqrt{f(x,y)}\bigg|d(x \times y)}\right)^2 \\
 &= \left\langle X\sqrt{f(X,Y)}, Y\sqrt{f(X,Y)} \right\rangle^2 \\
 &\leq \left\langle X\sqrt{f(X,Y)}, X\sqrt{f(X,Y)} \right\rangle
 \left\langle Y\sqrt{f(X,Y)}, Y\sqrt{f(X,Y)} \right\rangle \\
 &= E[|X^2|]E[|Y^2|]
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes your comment about the law of the unconscious statistician is what explains my confusion. By the way, by $\langle|X\sqrt{\mathbb{P}}|,|Y\sqrt{\mathbb{P}}|\rangle$ you are just referring to the dot product, correct? In any case, the square root of the probability measure is a bit weird though, though I follow it logically. I'm not sure how it would work using a lebesque integral...

Comment: Yes, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the dot product. I'll add the general case.